# TreeView in C# : checked subnodes don't stay checked, and can't use ref parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, tree, treeview

I'm trying to extend TreeView in C# with a few methods to populate the tree and check subnodes. However, I'm running into a design issue where I can't access the actual TreeView's nodes to check them.

The method PopulateTree() works as intended, and CheckBoxesBelow() is successfully called from the WPF.

[image]

```
private void BusinessUnitsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            busUnitTreeView.PopulateTree(busUnitTreeView.GetTreeItems("BU"));
        }

// a box is checked, so recursively check all boxes below
private void busUnitTreeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
  {
       busUnitTreeView.CheckBoxesBelow(sender,ref e);      
  }
```

However, nodes don't stay checked after closing the menu. This is because nodes are being created locally and aren't referencing the original Tree's nodes. However, I can't add "ref" in there or the following error happens:

```
A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter
```

Looking at a number of various threads on the same error, it looks like I'd have to create new objects and return them, then set the original object to the new object. This doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

```
// used to check all sub boxes of a node
        public void CheckBoxesBelow(object sender,ref TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (busy) return;
            busy = true;
            try
            {
                CheckNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
            }
            finally
            {
                busy = false;
            }
        }

        private void CheckNodes(TreeNode node, bool check)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            {
                child.Checked = check;
                CheckNodes(child, check);
            }
        }
```

Is there a better solution for how I could check a Tree's nodes? In C++ it would be easy with pointers, but I'm at a loss of how to do it here.

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of passing e by reference?  You're not changing the reference to a new instance anywhere in your methods, so passing as a ref parameter shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use DataBinding for this purpose. This will solve all your problems. In the busUnitTreeView_AfterCheck event handler you will simply retrieve the underlying data structure from the DataContext of the sender, and set the property you want to true or false in all subnodes.